# iOS - JSValue retaining but not releasing object

Tags: javascript, ios

I am working on an iOS codebase that has an object which holds a JSContext, and is also adding that object to it's own JSContext with a JSValue:

```
JSValue *jsBridgedObject = [JSValue valueWithObject:self inContext:context];
context[@"Object"] = jsBridgedObject;
```

This seems to work as `valueWithObject`creates a strong reference to object, however it also seems to be causing a retain cycle as I am unable to release the object afterwards from the context. What is the way to do this?

Comment: What variant of JavaScript is that written in (if it is)? Please add a question tag for it.

Comment: It's iOS, I've amended the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a very late follow up, I ended up creating a new class in between the JSContext owner and the JSContext, acting like a bridge. The JSContext captures the bridge, which receives the callbacks from the JavaScript code and forwards them on to the owner, which is a weak delegate of the bridge.